# Delete function error in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Below is my code for deleting records from a page

```
<?php
class DamageController extends AppController {
$damage = $this->Damage->find("all");
$this->Damage->delete($user['Damage']['id']);
 }
?>
```

But it does not delete data , instead says data not received..What is the error?

Comment: Where is your method declaration (`public function action_name()`)? Where is `$user` being set?

Comment: Your example code is not valid PHP code so would never work. What are you actually trying to achieve and in what version of CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete record, you should do it by setting id first.

```
$Model->id = $id;
$Model->delete ();
```